# Shortcut for Thunderbird's unread mails

Tags: thunderbird

Thunderbird has in "Quick filter" the option to show Unread mails only (or all). Is there any keyboard shortcut for that?

Answer (score 2):

As far as keyboard shortcuts are concerned I don't think there is what you want, but a mouse click on the title unread messages is just as fast.

[image]

And here you have all the keyboard shortcuts available and there are many.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts#w_moving-around-thunderbird

I forgot one thing, maybe you don't have the filter bar active ?
it is in french but it's very probably at the same place

[image]

have a nice day !

Comment: I have the bar active. But I want to voice control this action via Talon (voice-control) and sending few keypresses is much easier than simulating mouse clicks at a very specific button.